# Excerpt keep stripping <a> tags

Tags: html, excerpt

I have the following function to display my excerpt

```
  <?php function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
global $post;
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    //Add the allowed HTML tags separated by a comma.
    $allowed_tags = '<p>,<a>,<em>,<strong>,<img src />,<audio><video>';  
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);

    //Change the excerpt word count.
    $excerpt_word_count = 105; 
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 

    //Change the excerpt ending.
    $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&hellip;' . __( 'Read more about this article <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</a>'; 
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt'); ?>
```

My problem is, my `<a>` tags still get stripped. I followed a couple examples, and all suggest adding the `<a>` tag to the `$allowed_tags`, but even that doesn't solve the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'get_the_content_limit_allowedtags', 'get_the_content_limit_custom_allowedtags' );

function get_the_content_limit_custom_allowedtags() {
// Add custom tags to this string
return '<script>,<style>,<br>,<em>,<i>,<ul>,<ol>,<li>,<a>'; 
}
```

You can also add this code in your functions file and customize which tags you want to allow in excerpts.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I can see the `<a>` now,  just one problem.  Although I can see the `<a>` tag, I can't see the image inside.  Is there more to images than just the `<a>` tag

Comment: Got the `<img>` tag wrong. Used `<img src />`

Comment: Brad, just one thing I forgot to add last night, you don't need the `add_filter( 'get_the_content_limit_allowedtags', 'get_the_content_limit_custom_allowedtags' );
` part. You want to add to a filter that doesn't exist. Your code works just fine without that piece of code